# Microsoft Word Design. How do contain a box within a circle?

Tags: microsoft-word

[image: photo]

How do I contain the rectangle box within the circle? I'm trying to make the left of the rectangle of one color, and the rectangle itself of the blue color

Comment: Use an image editor. Word processors aren't really designed for complex image manipulation.

Comment: what's a beginner friendly image editor? Or you have something that you can recommend? Thanks! @DavidPostill

Comment: [Paint.NET](https://www.getpaint.net/).

Comment: I use [GIMP - GNU Image Manipulation Program](https://www.gimp.org/). And before that PaintShopPro. Might be a bit of a learning curve though ...